# Java array sorting by classes

Tags: java, arrays

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
public class Item {
    private int worth;

    public Item(int worth) {
        this.worth = worth;
    }

    public int getWorth() { return worth; }
}

public class Foo {
    public Foo() {
       List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
       items.add(new Item(50));
       items.add(new Item(892));
       items.add(new Item(12));
       // Sort?
    }
}
```

So that the items will be ordered like so

```
List{
    Item(892)
    Item(50)
    Item(12)
}
```

Not exactly sure where I should go from here, the Arrays.sort() method would be amazing if I could figure out how to sort it by an integer inside of the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own class that implements `Comparator<Item>`.  The only method you need to define is [the `compare` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-), which compares 2 `Item`s.  It returns a negative number, 0, or a positive number depending on whether the first item is less than, equal to, or greater than the second item, respectively.

In this case, with a descending sort, when the first item is less than the second item return a positive number, and when the first item is greater than the second item, return a negative number.  This will create a descending order.

`Arrays.sort` is for arrays, but `Collections.sort` does the same thing for collections (and it uses `Arrays.sort` internally anyway).  Both methods only need to know from the caller how to compare the items, so that it can sort them correctly.

Pass an instance of your `Comparator` to a call to [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-), and it will sort your list for you.

Comment: Thanks. the links made this really simple.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Foo constructor as follows

```
public Foo() {
   List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
   items.add(new Item(50));
   items.add(new Item(892));
   items.add(new Item(12));
   Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<Item>() {

        public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {

            return    Integer.valueOf(o1.getWorth()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2.getWorth()));
    }
    });
}
```